# Higher dimensional riemann mapping theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

Riemann mapping theorem states that any simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ is conformally diffeomorphic to unit disc. Is it true in higher dimensions?  I guess the answer is no. I read a few papers which say that only a few regions in higher dimensions are conformally diffeomorphic to the unit ball. I think the reason might be due to Liouville's theorem that conformal mappings are just Mobius transformations in higher dimensions, so it's quite restricted. But I am still curious about those examples that are conformally diffeomorphic to the unit ball, are they only the images of the unit ball under random Mobius transformations? The reason I am thinking about this is that I want to see a conformal diffeomorphism between the unit ball and a smooth convex body, I think in general there is no such map.

Comment: See $\S 1.4$ in https://www.jirka.org/scv/scv.pdf.

Comment: You can also read about this in Fritzsche-Grauert „From holomorphic functions to complex manifolds“.

Comment: It may be interesting that the complex $2$-ball and the product of two complex disks are _not_ biholomorphic... with a relatively easy proof by determining (the connected component of) their holo auto groups via Schwarz' lemma, and then doing a little Lie theory to demonstrate that those two groups ($PSL_2(\mathbb R)^2$ and $PU(2,1)$) are not isomorphic.